# Getting different results from Keras model.evaluate and model.predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, predict

I have trained a model to predict topic categories using word2vec and an lstm model using keras and got about 98% accuracy during training, I saved the model then loaded it into another file for trying on the test set, I used `model.evaluate` and `model.predict` and the results were very different.

I'm using keras with tensorflow as a backend, the model summary is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 22)                19624     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 22)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 40)                920       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 40)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 20,544
Trainable params: 20,544
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The code:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.load_weights(os.path.join('model', 'lstm_model_weights.hdf5'))
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)

print()
print('Score: %1.4f' % score)
print('Evaluation Accuracy: %1.2f%%' % (acc*100))

predicted = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=batch_size)
acc2 = np.count_nonzero(predicted.argmax(1) == y_test.argmax(1))/y_test.shape[0]
print('Prediction Accuracy: %1.2f%%' % (acc2*100))
```

The output of this code is

```
39680/40171 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s  
Score: 0.1192
Evaluation Accuracy: 97.50%
Prediction Accuracy: 9.03%
```

Can anyone tell me what did I miss?

Comment: What is the last layer's activation? Why are using binary cross entropy loss when your output layer has 40 neurons?

Comment: Actually that was it, I changed the loss and forgot about it, after changing it to categorical_crossentropy I got the same accuracy for both, thanks @Mitiku.
Please confirm if you saw my comment because I will probably delete the post

Comment: This question might be useful if some one might face similar problem in the future. Please consider that before deleting the question.

Comment: @MinaMelek thank you for not deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate and Predict are 2 distinct methods as you can check on Keras documentation.

`model.evaluate` purpose is to evaluate the performance of a model on a given dataset and will return the model loss and specified metrics at `model.compile` for the given dataset. It is usually useful in the test dataset. Imagine `model.evaluate` as a `model.fit` but where the parameters are static (are not trainable): it will take the given dataset as input pass it through the model (1 epoch) and calculate and return the loss and metrics.

`model.predict` on the other hand is similar. Still, instead of returning loss and metrics, it will return an array with the predicted classes for each example on the given dataset.

So in your example, you shouldn't interpret `predicted` as a score but as a class of your model.

Check out [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) for more in-depth details.